# sqLite Android..Unfortunately, applicaton has stopped

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am new to Android Programming.. I am trying to create sqLite Database in android Here is my code

```
sqLitee.java
package com.example.sqlite;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class sqLitee extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{

    public static final String DB_NAME="student.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="student";
    public static final String COL_1="ID";
    public static final String COL_2="FIRST_NAME";
    public static final String COL_3="LAST_NAME";
    public static final String COL_4="MARKS";

    public sqLitee(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DB_NAME,null, 1);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT, FIRST_NAME TEXT, LAST_NAME TEXT, MARKS INTEGER)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }


}

MainActivity.java

package com.example.sqlite;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    sqLitee myDB;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myDB = new sqLitee(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


}
```

When I am trying to run it on Android virtual Device , It says unfortunately , sqLite has stopped..
Thanks

Comment: Where is your LogCat..??

Comment: Try moving `myDB = new sqLitee(this);` below `setContentView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this line in your sqllite constructor:

```
SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
```

you try to get the db, which is currently initializing.

Comment: Thanks guys it worked.. successfully executed the app

Comment: The database named student.db is created but the table named student in not created.. i am using sqLite manager for it..

Comment: This is not a problem. Removing this line just prevents `onCreate()` from being run and the syntax problem from there causing an exception.

Comment: yes you are right, but calling onCreate inside the Constructor, is something you should never do, also because the Constructor is called in onCreate of Activity, so on UI Thread. so fixing just the autoincrement, could still cause an ANR.

Answer (score 0):

There's a syntax error in your `CREATE TABLE` SQL. `AUTO INCREMENT` should be `AUTOINCREMENT`.

As always, first see the logcat for exception stacktrace and to learn what is failing and where.